# Ajax request showing error message while successfull updation laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In the `laravel` update form The code for controller is:

```
public function edit(){
    $inputValue = [
        'id' => Input::get('id'),
        'name' => Input::get('name'),
        'parent_id' => Input::get('parent_id'),
        'color' => Input::get('color'),
        'description' => Input::get('notes')
    ];

    $validator = \Validator::make( $inputValue, \Resource::getEditFolderRules() );

    // Validate the input and return correct response
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json([
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()
        ]);
    }

    $resource = $this->repo->updateFolderBasicDetail($inputValue);
    return Response::json([
        'success' => true,
        'url' => \URL::route('folder-detail', $inputValue['id'])
    ]);
}
```

and js is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#edit-folder").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($("#edit-folder").valid() == true){
                var description = CKEDITOR.instances.edit_folder_ckeditor1.getData();
                $('#notes').val(description);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ URL::to('folder/edit') }}",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $( this ).serialize(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        var errorString = '<ul class="msg msg_unsuccess">';
                        var success = 'Folder is updated.';
                        errorString += '<li>' + success + '</li>';
                        errorString += '</ul>';
                        $('#sucessmsg').html(errorString).delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        $('.modal-content').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        $('.fade').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                    },
                    error:function(data) {
                        var errorString = '<ul class="msg msg_success">';
                        var error = 'Folder is not updated.';
                        errorString += '<li>' + error + '</li>';
                        errorString += '</ul>';
                        $('#sucessmsg').html(errorString).delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        $('.modal-content').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        $('.fade').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                        setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},3000);


                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

but when I update the folder it is updating and message is displaying from  `error:function`.

don't understand where I am wrong Please help me out.

Comment: Not that this is the problem, but why is the class `msg_unsuccess` in the `success` function, and the class `msg_success` in the `error` function...?

Comment: I'm not using laravel, but are you sure that your server response is a `json` string?

Comment: @ImClarky this class is for giving background color of message

Comment: You should probably be handling whether the folder was updated or not in the `success` function. The `error` function is mainly used when the ajax request itself fails. [jQuery Ajax Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: but it is not picking the success part even the folder detail is updated

Comment: improved formatting: please use 4-space-intending for code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use AJAX in Laravel 5.2 with routes, created variable url and variable  token(if need), in php file where views, before included script

```
<script>
    var token = '{{ Session::token()}}';
    var url = '{{ route('select_cafe') }}';
</script> 
<script src="{{asset('/script/select_cafe.js')}}" ></script>
```